# Working with NSDictionary to array

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I have 2 `NSArray` with contents ids and the other contents are urls

But when I create `NSDictionary` its look like this (from `NSLog`):

```
2015-07-03 17:10:51.072 hibridTesting[4950:166675] {
    (
) =     (
);
    (
    30,
    31
) =     (
    "https://www.google.com",
    "https://www.yahoo.com"
);
    (
    10,
    11,
    12,
    13
) =     (
    "https://www.facebook.com/",
    "https://www.sapo.pt",
    "https://www.sapo.pt",
    "https://www.sapo.pt"
);
    (
    20,
    21,
    22,
    23,
    24,
    25
) =     (
    "https://www.google.com",
    "https://www.google.com",
    "https://www.google.com",
    "https://www.google.com",
    "https://www.google.com",
    "https://www.google.com"
);
}
```

and if I do this

```
arrayDeSitesSubmenus = [mydictionary objectForKey:@"21"];
```

and if I print my `arrayDeSitesSubmenus` it says `nil`.

What I want is each id for url, and what I understand is group of keys to a group of urls

EDIT:

my logs from arrays is:

```
2015-07-03 17:33:55.771 hibridTesting[5122:174427] (
    (
    "https://www.facebook.com/",
    "https://www.sapo.pt",
    "https://www.sapo.pt",
    "https://www.sapo.pt"
),
    (
    "https://www.google.com",
    "https://www.google.com",
    "https://www.google.com",
    "https://www.google.com",
    "https://www.google.com",
    "https://www.google.com"
),
    (
    "https://www.google.com",
    "https://www.yahoo.com"
),
    (
),
    (
),
    (
),
    (
)
)
2015-07-03 17:33:55.771 hibridTesting[5122:174427] (
     (
    10,
    11,
    12,
    13
),
    (
    20,
    21,
    22,
    23,
    24,
    25
),
    (
    30,
    31
),
    (
),
    (
),
    (
),
    (
)
)
```

i take my arrays from xmlparse , thats why my logs looks like that
thanks.

Comment: You didn't create correctly your `NSDictionary`. The key is not @"21", but a `NSArray` from 20 to 25 with the corresponding URL. Use this: `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:arrayURLs forKeys:arrayIds];`

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating your `NSDictionary`?

When creating NSDictionary you have two option:

first:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"value1", @"key1", nil];
```

the other is

```
NSDictionary *mdictionary = @{ @"key1" : @"value1" };
```

Since you already have the array for both keys and values, the best one for you is using `initWithObjects:forKeys` which accepts array of values and keys and arrange accordingly.

```
NSArray *keys = @[@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5"];

NSArray *values = @[@"value1", @"value2", @"value3", @"value4", @"value5"];

NSDictionary *dictionary   = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];
```

and the output will be:

```
{
    1 = value1;
    2 = value2;
    3 = value3;
    4 = value4;
    5 = value5;
}
```

but if your key are numbers like

```
NSArray *keys = @[@1, @2, @3, @4, @5];

NSArray *values = @[@"value1", @"value2", @"value3", @"value4", @"value5"];

NSDictionary *dictionary   = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];

//This is wrong and will return (null)
//
//NSLog(@"%@", [dictionary objectForKey:@"1"]); 

The correct one is:
NSLog(@"%@", [dictionary objectForKey:@1]);
or
NSLog(@"%@", [dictionary objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]);
```

Hope this is helpful to you. Cheers!

Comment: hi , thanks mate , for the help . but already fix what i want sorry for bother you , its was bad logic , i m new in programing , and objective c is kind hard , i try other think , in my xml i have menuIDs , so it is more easy to work , now i have id1 4urls id2 6urls etc... so know i can do what i want